# How To capitalize The First Letter Of Every Word In The Post Title

Tags: posts, title

Hello i wonder if you can help me. How do you make to post titles capitalize the first letter of every word?

Is there a way to do it in wordpress?

Comment: Then there's CSS: `.entry-title { text-transform: capitalize; }`

Answer (score 2):

The code below was assembled of different pieces I've found around and it was not tested. Consider it as an idea only.

```
<?php
add_filter( 'the_title', 'my_capitalize_title', 10, 2 );

function my_capitalize_title( $title, $id ) {

    // get separate words
    $words = preg_split( '/[^\w]*([\s]+[^\w]*|$)/', $title, NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY );

    $stop_words = array(
        'the', //
        'a',
        'and',
        'of',
    );

    $title_case = '';

    foreach( $words as $word ) {
        // concatenate stop word intact
        if ( in_array( $word, $stop_words ) ) {
            $title_case .= $word;
        }
        // or concatenate capitalized word
        $title_case .=  ucfirst( $word );
    }

    return $title_case;
}
```

You have to polish the idea: you don't want "**The** Simpsons" to become "**the** Simpsons".

Answer (score 0):

Is this for `<title></title>` or output title?

If **output title**, call your title as `echo ucwords( get_the_title() );` on your page.

If **`<title></title>`**, you can do the same as above by applying a filter to `wpseo_title` in your functions file.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress is based on PHP. So, a better question might be, "Is there a PHP function that will do this?" The answer given above [ucwords](https://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php); is correct. However, there may be words you don't want capitalized, such as "a", "an" or "the". If that is the case, there needs to be a filter that prevents these words from being capitalized. However, that is beyond the scope of this question.